# Define a function and use it for multiple files or modules in python

Tags: python, excel, python-3.6

How to create a function to format excel file which can be used for multiple python files or modules. i can understand the problem with variables. i am expecting python to load variables from main file.

I have defined one function to format the excel sheet. it's working fine when i am using it on the same module. but, i want that function to be used for multiple files.

i have used below code

```
#my function in a file myfunction

def myformatfunction():

    workbook = writer.book
    worksheet = writer.sheets['report']

    total_fmt = workbook.add_format({'align': 'right', 'num_format': '$#,##0',
                                 'bold': True, 'bottom':6})

    worksheet.set_column('A:F', 20)
    worksheet.set_column('G:G', 20, total_fmt)

    writer.save()
```

```
#this is my main file where i want to use defined function
# i have dataframe which will read excel file

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('E:/FunctionOut2.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, index=False, sheet_name='report')


myformatfunction()
```

this is working fine when i am using it on same module. How to use it for multiple python files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to use the same function in other Python files, you can define it in a different file and import that one.
For example, you can create a file named "utils.py" in the same directory as the files where you'd like to use it, and define your function there.
Most likely though, the files where you want to use the function are not all in the same directory. You can put utils.py in a higher directory accessible to all of them, or add the directory where utils.py is to the path where Python looks for imported modules.

For example:

*src/utils/utils.py*

```
def myfunction(parameters):
    # you'll also need params if you want to call if for different dataframes
    (...)
    return
```

*src/files/file1.py* (where you'll call the function)

```
import sys
sys.path.append("src/utils") # this includes src/utils to the list of paths where python will look for the modules you want to import
from utils import * # or import myfunction only

(...)
myfunction(df)
```

In general you should define common functions in a separate file and import it into every file where you need the functions.

Comment: Thank  you.. it's working when i assigned parameters to the function.